# How to get a list that include all Actionscript 3 api name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm working on a swf file source code obfuscator, for some reason I need a list that include all actionscript 3 api name. How to get it ? Should I need check all of the as3 api doc and make the list manual ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find some word lists online for various text editors (UltraEdit, NotePad++, etc.). Here's the one I'm using:

```
as
break
case class continue catch const
default do dynamic delete
else extends each
false for function
get
if in is import instanceof internal include
mx_internal
new null namespace
on override
private prototype public package protected
return
switch static super set
true this try throw
undefined use
var
while

abs accept accessibilityProperties acos actionScriptVersion actionsList activating active
activeVideoPlayerIndex activityLevel addASCuePoint addCallback addChild addChildAt addColumn addColumnAt
addDelayedInstance addEventListener addHeader addItem addItemAt addItems addItemsAt addKeyframe
addNamespace addPage addRadioButton addXMLPath added affectsTweenable album align allowDomain
allowInsecureDomain allowMultipleSelection alpha alphaMultiplier alphaOffset alphas altKey
alwaysShowSelection angle antiAliasType appendChild appendText applicationDomain apply applyFilter
areInaccessibleObjectsUnderPoint areSoundsInaccessible artist ascent asin atan atan2 attachAudio
attachCamera attachNetStream attribute attributes autoLayout autoLoad autoPlay autoRepeat autoReplace
autoRewind autoSize avHardwareDisable available
backButton background backgroundColor backgroundPadding bandwidth barPadding barSkin begin
beginBitmapFill beginFill beginGradientFill bias bitmapData bitrate blank blendMode blockIndent
blueMultiplier blueOffset blurX blurY border borderColor bottomRight bottomScrollV brightness
bringVideoPlayerToFront browse bubbles bufferLength bufferTime buffering bufferingBar
bufferingBarHidesAndDisablesOthers builtInItems bullet buttonDown buttonMode buttonWidth bytesAvailable
bytesLoaded bytesTotal
cacheAsBitmap call callProperty callee cancelable capsLock caption captionButton captionCuePointObject
captionTarget captionTargetName caretIndex ceil cellRenderer changeList changeType charAt charCode
charCodeAt charCount checkPolicyFile checkXMLStatus child childAllowsParent childIndex childNodes children
clamp clear clearComponentStyle clearRendererStyle clearSelection clearStyle clickTarget client clone
cloneNode close closeVideoPlayer code color colorTransform colorWell colors column columnCount
columnDividerSkin columnIndex columnStretchCursorSkin columnWidth columns comment comments compare
componentX componentY compress computeSpectrum concat concatenatedColorTransform concatenatedMatrix
condenseWhite connect connectAgain connectToURL connected connectedProxyType constructor contains
containsPoint containsRect content contentAppearance contentLoaderInfo contentPadding contentType
contextMenu contextMenuOwner continueTo conversionMode copy copyChannel copyPixels cos createBox
createElement createGradientBox createItemEditor createTextNode creationDate creator ctrlKey cuePoints
currentCount currentDomain currentFPS currentFrame currentLabel currentLabels currentScene currentTarget
curveTo customItems
dataField dataFormat dataProvider date dateUTC day dayUTC deactivate deblocking decode defaultButton
defaultButtonEnabled defaultObjectEncoding defaultSettings defaultTextFormat delay deleteProperty delta
deltaTransformPoint descendants descent description destroyItemEditor dimensions direction disabledAlpha
disabledIcon disabledSkin disabledTextFormat dispatchEvent displayAsPassword displayMode displayState
dispose distance divisor doConversion docTypeDecl domain dotall doubleClickEnabled downArrowDisabledSkin
downArrowDownSkin downArrowOverSkin downArrowUpSkin downIcon downSkin downState download draw drawCircle
drawEllipse drawFocus drawNow drawRect drawRoundRect dropTarget dropdown dropdownWidth duration
dynamicPropertyWriter
ease easeIn easeInOut easeNone easeOut easeQuadPercent easing easingFunction editField editable
editedItemPosition editedItemRenderer editorDataField elementType elements embedFonts emphasized
emphasizedPadding emphasizedSkin enableAccessibility enabled endFill endIndex endian enumerateFonts equals
error errorID escape eventPhase every exactSettings exec exp extended extension
fallbackServerName fforward fileList fillRect filter filters findCuePoint findFocusManagerComponent
findNearestCuePoint findNextCuePointWithName findText finish firstChild firstFrame floodFill floor flush
flvPlayback flvPlaybackName focus focusEnabled focusManager focusRect focusRectPadding focusRectSkin font
fontName fontSize fontStyle fontType forEach forceSimple formatToString forwardAndBack forwardButton frame
frameRate framesLoaded fromCharCode fromXML fromXMLString fullScreen fullScreenBackgroundColor
fullScreenButton fullScreenSkinDelay fullScreenTakeOver fullYear fullYearUTC func functionName
gain generateFilterRect genre getActions getBounds getCamera getCellRendererAt getCharBoundaries
getCharIndexAtPoint getChildAt getChildByName getChildIndex getColorBoundsRect getColorTransform
getColumnAt getColumnCount getColumnIndex getComponentStyle getCubicCoefficients getCubicRoots
getCurrentKeyframe getDate getDay getDefaultLang getDefinition getDescendants getFilters
getFirstCharInParagraph getFocus getFullYear getGroup getHours getImageReference getItemAt getItemIndex
getLineIndexAtPoint getLineIndexOfChar getLineLength getLineMetrics getLineOffset getLineText getLocal
getMicrophone getMilliseconds getMinutes getMonth getNamespaceForPrefix getNextFocusManagerComponent
getNextKeyframe getObjectsUnderPoint getParagraphLength getPixel getPixel32 getPixels
getPrefixForNamespace getProperty getQuadraticRoots getRadioButtonAt getRadioButtonIndex getRect getRemote
getRendererStyle getRotation getRotationRadians getScaleX getScaleY getSeconds getSelected getSelectedText
getSingleValue getSkewX getSkewXRadians getSkewY getSkewYRadians getStackTrace getStyle getStyleDefinition
getText getTextFormat getTextRunInfo getTime getTimezoneOffset getTween getUTCDate getUTCDay
getUTCFullYear getUTCHours getUTCMilliseconds getUTCMinutes getUTCMonth getUTCSeconds getValue
getVideoPlayer getYForX global globalToLocal gotoAndPlay gotoAndStop graphics greenMultiplier greenOffset
gridFitType group groupName
hasAccessibility hasAudio hasAudioEncoder hasChildNodes hasComplexContent hasDefinition hasEmbeddedVideo
hasEventListener hasGlyphs hasIME hasMP3 hasOwnProperty hasPrinting hasProperty hasScreenBroadcast
hasScreenPlayback hasSimpleContent hasStreamingAudio hasStreamingVideo hasTLS hasVideoEncoder
headerDisabledSkin headerDisabledTextFormat headerDownSkin headerHeight headerOverSkin headerRenderer
headerSortArrowAscSkin headerSortArrowDescSkin headerText headerTextFormat headerTextPadding headerUpSkin
height helperDone hexValue hideBuiltInItems hideFocus hideObject highlightAlpha highlightColor hitArea
hitTest hitTestObject hitTestPoint hitTestState hitTestTextNearPos horizontalLineScrollSize
horizontalPageScrollSize horizontalScrollBar horizontalScrollPolicy horizontalScrollPosition hours
hoursUTC htmlText
iNCManagerClass icon iconField iconFunction id3 idMap identity idleTimeout ignoreCase ignoreComments isNaN
ignoreProcessingInstructions ignoreWhite ignoreWhitespace imagePadding ime imeMode inScopeNamespaces
indent indeterminate indeterminateBar indeterminateSkin index indexOf inflate inflatePoint info initialize
inner innerHeight innerWidth insertBefore insertChildAfter insertChildBefore insideCutoff installActions
instanceName interpolate interpolateColor interpolateFilter interpolateFilters interpolateTransform
intersection intersects invalidate invalidateItem invalidateItemAt invalidateList invert isAccessible
isAttribute isBuffering isDebugger isDefaultPrevented isEmpty isFLVCuePointEnabled isFocusInaccessible
isItemSelected isLive isPlaying isPrototypeOf isRTMP item itemEditor itemEditorInstance itemRenderer
itemToCellRenderer itemToLabel items
join
kerning keyCode keyFrameInterval keyLocation keyframes keyframesCompact knockout
labelField labelFunction labelPlacement labels language languageCodeArray lastChild lastIndex lastIndexOf
leading left leftMargin leftPeak leftToLeft leftToRight length letterSpacing level lineGradientStyle
lineScrollSize lineStyle lineTo linkageID listData liveDelay liveDragging load loadBytes loadLanguageXML
loadPolicyFile loadString loadStringEx loader loaderInfo loaderURL localFileReadDisable localName
localToGlobal localX localY localeCompare lock log loop loopback looping
macType maintainAspectRatio manufacturer map mapBitmap mapPoint mask match matchInternalPointWithExternal
matrix matrixX matrixY max maxChars maxHorizontalScrollPosition maxLevel maxScrollH maxScrollPosition
maxScrollV maxVerticalScrollPosition maximum merge mergeStyles message metadata metadataLoaded method
milliseconds millisecondsUTC min minColumnWidth minScrollPosition minWidth maxWidth minHeight maxHeight minimum minutes minutesUTC mode
modificationDate month monthUTC motion motionLevel motionTimeout mouseChildren mouseEnabled
mouseFocusEnabled mouseTarget mouseWheelEnabled mouseX mouseY moveTo multiline muteButton muted myInstance
name names namespaceDeclarations namespaceURI navigateToURL ncConnected ncMgr ncReconnected netConnection netStream
nextFrame nextName nextNameIndex nextScene nextSibling nextTabIndex nextValue noAutoLabeling nodeKind
nodeName nodeType nodeValue noise normalize numChildren numFrames numLines numLock numRadioButtons
obj objectEncoding objectID offset offsetPoint oldBounds oldRegistrationBounds onResize onUpdate
opaqueBackground open orientToPath orientation os outsideCutoff overIcon overSkin overState owner
pageHeight pageScrollSize pageSize pageWidth paletteMap pan paperHeight paperWidth parameters parent
parentAllowsChild parentDomain parentNode parse parseCSS parseXML pause pauseButton paused percentComplete
percentLoaded perlinNoise pixelAspectRatio pixelBounds pixelDissolve pixelSnapping play playButton
playPauseButton playWhenEnoughDownloaded playerType playheadPercentage playheadTime playheadUpdateInterval
points polar pop position positionMatrix pow preferredHeight preferredWidth prefix prependChild
preserveAlpha prettyIndent prettyPrinting prevFrame prevScene preventDefault preview previousSibling
previousValue print printAsBitmap processingInstructions progressInterval prompt prop propertyIsEnumerable
prototype proxyType publish push
quality
random rate ratios readBoolean readByte readBytes readDouble readExternal readFloat readInt readMultiByte
readObject readShort readUTF readUTFBytes readUnsignedByte readUnsignedInt readUnsignedShort reason
receiveAudio receiveVideo reconnect rect redMultiplier redOffset refreshPane registerFont registerInstance
registrationHeight registrationWidth registrationX registrationY relatedObject removeASCuePoint removeAll
removeAllColumns removeChild removeChildAt removeColumnAt removeEventListener removeItem removeItemAt
removeNamespace removeNode removeRadioButton repeatCount repeatDelay repeatInterval replace replaceItem
replaceItemAt replaceSelectedText replaceText requestHeaders reset resizable resizableColumns restrict
resume reverse rewind right rightMargin rightPeak rightToLeft rightToRight root rotate
rotateAroundExternalPoint rotateAroundInternalPoint rotateDirection rotateTimes rotation round row
rowCount rowHeight rowIndex running
sameDomain sandboxType save scale scale9Grid scaleContent scaleMode scaleX scaleY scenes screenColor
screenDPI screenResolutionX screenResolutionY scrollDrag scrollH scrollPolicy scrollPosition scrollRect
scrollTarget scrollToIndex scrollToSelected scrollV scrubbing search seconds secondsUTC securityDomain
seek seekBar seekBarInterval seekBarScrubTolerance seekPercent seekSeconds seekToNavCuePoint
seekToNextNavCuePoint seekToPrevNavCuePoint seekToPrevOffset selectable selected selectedColor
selectedData selectedDisabledIcon selectedDisabledSkin selectedDownIcon selectedDownSkin selectedIndex
selectedIndices selectedItem selectedItems selectedLabel selectedOverIcon selectedOverSkin selectedSkin
selectedUpIcon selectedUpSkin selection selectionBeginIndex selectionEndIndex send separatorBefore
serverString setAdvancedAntiAliasingTable setChildIndex setChildren setClipboard setComponentStyle
setCompositionString setDate setDefaultLang setDirty setEmpty setFLVCuePointEnabled setFocus setFullYear
setHours setKeyFrameInterval setLoadCallback setLocalName setLoopback setMilliseconds setMinutes setMode
setMonth setMotionLevel setMouseState setName setNamespace setPixel setPixel32 setPixels setProgress
setProperty setPropertyIsEnumerable setQuality setRendererStyle setRotation setRotationRadians setScale
setScaleX setScaleY setScrollProperties setSeconds setSelectColor setSelected setSelection setSettings
setSilenceLevel setSize setSkewX setSkewXRadians setSkewY setSkewYRadians setString setStyle setTextFormat
setTime setTint setUTCDate setUTCFullYear setUTCHours setUTCMilliseconds setUTCMinutes setUTCMonth
setUTCSeconds setUseEchoSuppression setValue size settings shadowAlpha shadowColor sharedEvents sharpness
shiftKey shortcut show showCaptions showDefaultContextMenu showFocus showFocusIndicator showHeaders
showSettings showTextField silenceLevel silenceTimeout silent simpleFormatting sin skewX skewY skin
skinAutoHide skinBackgroundAlpha skinBackgroundColor skinFadeTime slice sliderTrackDisabledSkin
sliderTrackSkin smoothing snapInterval some songName sortCompareFunction sortDescending sortIndex
sortItems sortItemsOn sortOn sortOptions sortable sortableColumns soundTransform source sourceField
sourceFunction spaceColumnsEqually splice split sqrt stage stageFocusRect stageHeight stageWidth stageX
stageY start startDrag startIndex startTransition stateResponsive stepSize stop stopAll stopButton
stopDrag sendToURL stopImmediatePropagation stopPropagation streamHeight streamLength streamName streamWidth
strength stringIDArray styleNames styleSheet substr substring subtract swapChildren swapChildrenAt
swatchHeight swatchPadding swatchSelectedSkin swatchSkin swatchWidth swfVersion symbolName
tabChildren tabEnabled tabIndex tabStops tan target test text textColor textField textFieldSkin textFormat
textHeight textOverlayAlpha textPadding textSnapshot textWidth thickness threshold thumbArrowUpSkin
thumbDisabledSkin thumbDownSkin thumbIcon thumbOverSkin thumbUpSkin tickInterval tickSkin time timeout
timezoneOffset tintColor tintMultiplier toArray toDateString toExponential toFixed toLocaleDateString
toLocaleLowerCase toLocaleString toLocaleTimeString toLocaleUpperCase toLowerCase toPrecision toString
toTimeString toUTCString toUpperCase toXMLString toggle togglePause topLeft totalFrames totalMemory
totalTime trackAsMenu trackDisabledSkin trackDownSkin trackOverSkin trackSkin trackUpSkin transform
transformPoint transformationPoint translate transparent triggerEvent tweenScale tweenSnap tweenSync
tweens tx ty type trace
uncompress underline uninstallActions union unlock unshift upArrowDisabledSkin upArrowDownSkin
upArrowOverSkin upArrowUpSkin upIcon upSkin upState update updateAfterEvent updateProperties upload uri
url useBitmapScrolling useCodePage useEchoSuppression useHandCursor useRichTextClipboard useSeconds
usingTLS
validateNow value valueOf verticalLineScrollSize verticalPageScrollSize verticalScrollBar
verticalScrollPolicy verticalScrollPosition videoHeight videoPlayer videoPlayerIndex videoWidth visible
visibleVideoPlayerIndex volume volumeBar volumeBarInterval volumeBarScrubTolerance vp
width willTrigger wordWrap writeBoolean writeByte writeBytes writeDouble writeDynamicProperties
writeDynamicProperty writeExternal writeFloat writeInt writeMultiByte writeObject writeShort writeUTF
writeUTFBytes writeUnsignedInt
x xmlDecl
y year yoyo
zoom

AVM1Movie AccImpl Accessibility AccessibilityProperties ActionScriptVersion ActivityEvent Animator
AntiAliasType ApplicationDomain ArgumentError Array AsyncErrorEvent AutoLayoutEvent
Back BaseButton BaseScrollPane BevelFilter BezierEase BezierSegment Bitmap BitmapData BitmapDataChannel
BitmapFilter BitmapFilterQuality BitmapFilterType BlendMode Blinds BlurFilter Boolean Bounce Button
ButtonAccImpl ButtonLabelPlacement ByteArray
CSMSettings Camera Capabilities CapsStyle CaptionChangeEvent CaptionTargetEvent CellRenderer CheckBox
CheckBoxAccImpl Circular Class Color ColorMatrixFilter ColorPicker ColorPickerEvent ColorTransform
ComboBox ComboBoxAccImpl ComponentEvent ContextMenu ContextMenuBuiltInItems ContextMenuEvent
ContextMenuItem ConvolutionFilter Cubic CuePointType CustomActions CustomEase
DataChangeEvent DataChangeType DataEvent DataGrid DataGridAccImpl DataGridCellEditor DataGridColumn
DataGridEvent DataGridEventReason DataProvider Date DefinitionError Dictionary DisplacementMapFilter
DisplacementMapFilterMode DisplayObject DisplayObjectContainer DropShadowFilter
EOFError Elastic Endian Error ErrorEvent EvalError Event EventDispatcher EventPhase Exponential
ExternalInterface
FLVPlayback FLVPlaybackCaptioning Fade FileFilter FileReference FileReferenceList Fly FocusEvent
FocusManager Font FontStyle FontType FrameLabel FullScreenEvent Function FunctionEase
GlowFilter GradientBevelFilter GradientGlowFilter GradientType Graphics GridFitType
HTTPStatusEvent HeaderRenderer
IBitmapDrawable ICellRenderer ID3Info IDataInput IDataOutput IDynamicPropertyOutput IDynamicPropertyWriter
IEventDispatcher IExternalizable IFocusManager IFocusManagerComponent IFocusManagerGroup IME
IMEConversionMode IMEEvent INCManager IOError IOErrorEvent ITween IVPEvent IllegalOperationError ImageCell
IndeterminateBar InteractionInputType InteractiveObject InterpolationMethod InvalidSWFError
InvalidationType Iris
JointStyle
KeyLocation Keyboard KeyboardEvent Keyframe
Label LabelButton LabelButtonAccImpl LayoutEvent LineScaleMode Linear List ListAccImpl ListData ListEvent
LivePreviewParent Loader LoaderContext LoaderInfo LocalConnection Locale
Math Matrix MatrixTransformer MemoryError MetadataEvent Microphone MorphShape Motion MotionEvent Mouse
MouseEvent MovieClip Matrix3D
NCManager NCManagerNative Namespace NetConnection NetStatusEvent NetStream None Number NumericStepper
Object ObjectEncoding
Photo PixelDissolve PixelSnapping Point PrintJob PrintJobOptions PrintJobOrientation ProgressBar
ProgressBarDirection ProgressBarMode ProgressEvent Proxy
QName Quadratic Quartic Quintic
RadioButton RadioButtonAccImpl RadioButtonGroup RangeError Rectangle ReferenceError RegExp Regular
Responder Rotate RotateDirection
SWFVersion Scene ScriptTimeoutError ScrollBar ScrollBarDirection ScrollEvent ScrollPane ScrollPolicy
Security SecurityDomain SecurityError SecurityErrorEvent SecurityPanel SelectableList
SelectableListAccImpl Shape SharedObject SharedObjectFlushStatus SimpleButton SimpleCollectionItem
SimpleEase Sine SkinErrorEvent Slider SliderDirection SliderEvent SliderEventClickTarget Socket Sound
SoundChannel SoundEvent SoundLoaderContext SoundMixer SoundTransform Source SpreadMethod Sprite Squeeze
StackOverflowError Stage StageAlign StageDisplayState StageQuality StageScaleMode StaticText StatusEvent
String Strong StyleManager StyleSheet SyncEvent SyntaxError System
TextArea TextColorType TextDisplayMode TextEvent TextField TextFieldAutoSize TextFieldType TextFormat
TextFormatAlign TextInput TextLineMetrics TextRenderer TextSnapshot TileList TileListAccImpl
TileListCollectionItem TileListData Timer TimerEvent Transform Transition TransitionManager Tween
TweenEvent Tweenables TypeError TweenMax TweenLite TimelineMax TimelineLite
UIComponent UIComponentAccImpl UILoader UIScrollBar URIError URLLoader URLLoaderDataFormat URLRequest
URLRequestHeader URLRequestMethod URLStream URLVariables Utils3D
VerifyError Video VideoAlign VideoError VideoEvent VideoPlayer VideoProgressEvent VideoScaleMode Vector Vector3D
VideoState
Wipe
XML XMLDocument XMLList XMLNode XMLNodeType XMLSocket XMLUI
Zoom
arguments
int
uint
void

__proto__
_accProps _alpha _currentframe _droptarget _focusrect _framesloaded _global _height _highquality _lockroot _name _parent _quality _root _rotation _soundbuftime _target _totalframes _url _visible _width _x _xmouse _xscale _y _ymouse _yscale _currentFrame
align attributes autoSize
background backgroundColor bold border borderColor bottomScroll bufferLength bufferTime builtInItems bullet bytesLoaded bytesTotal
callee caller capabilities caption childNodes 

ACTIONSCRIPT ACTIONSCRIPT2 ACTIONSCRIPT3 ACTIVATE ACTIVITY ADD ADDED_TO_STAGE ADVANCED ALL
ALPHANUMERIC_FULL ALPHANUMERIC_HALF ALWAYS AMF0 AMF3 ASYNC_ERROR AT_TARGET AUTO AUTO_LAYOUT AUTO_REWOUND
BACKSPACE BEST BEVEL BIG_ENDIAN BINARY BLUE BOLD BOLD_ITALIC BOTTOM BOTTOM_LEFT BOTTOM_RIGHT
BUBBLING_PHASE BUFFERING_STATE_ENTERED BUTTON_DOWN
CAMERA CANCEL CANCELLED CAPS_LOCK CAPTION_CHANGE CAPTION_TARGET_CREATED CAPTURING_PHASE CASEINSENSITIVE
CCW CENTER CHANGE CHINESE CIRCLE CLICK COLUMN_STRETCH COMPLETE CONNECTION_ERROR CONTROL CRT CUE_POINT CW
DARKEN DARK_COLOR DATA DATA_CHANGE DEFAULT DEFAULT_TIMEOUT DELETE DELETE_DEFAULT_PLAYER DESCENDING DEVICE
DIFFERENCE DISCONNECTED DOUBLE_CLICK DOWN DYNAMIC
E ELEMENT_NODE EMBEDDED END ENTER ENTER_FRAME ERASE ESCAPE EVENT EXACT_FIT
F1 F10 F11 F12 F13 F14 F15 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FAST_FORWARD FLASH1 FLASH2 FLASH3 FLASH4 FLASH5 FLASH6
FLASH7 FLASH8 FLASH9 FLUSHED FLV FOCUS_IN FOCUS_OUT FPS FULL FULL_SCREEN
GET GREEN
HARDLIGHT HEADER_RELEASE HIDE HIGH HOME HORIZONTAL HTTP_STATUS
IGNORE ILLEGAL_CUE_POINT IME_COMPOSITION IN INCMANAGER_CLASS_UNSET INIT INPUT INSERT INVALIDATE_ALL
INVALID_SEEK INVALID_SOURCE INVALID_XML IO_ERROR ITALIC ITEM_CLICK ITEM_DOUBLE_CLICK ITEM_EDIT_BEGIN
ITEM_EDIT_BEGINNING ITEM_EDIT_END ITEM_FOCUS_IN ITEM_FOCUS_OUT ITEM_ROLL_OUT ITEM_ROLL_OVER Infinity
JAPANESE_HIRAGANA JAPANESE_KATAKANA_FULL JAPANESE_KATAKANA_HALF JUSTIFY
KEYBOARD KEY_DOWN KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE KEY_UP KOREAN
LABEL_CHANGE LANDSCAPE LAYER LAYOUT LCD LIGHTEN LIGHT_COLOR LINEAR LINEAR_RGB LINK LITTLE_ENDIAN LN10 LN2
LOADING LOCAL_STORAGE LOCAL_TRUSTED LOCAL_WITH_FILE LOCAL_WITH_NETWORK LOG10E LOG2E LOW
MAINTAIN_ASPECT_RATIO MANUAL MAX_VALUE MEDIUM MENU_ITEM_SELECT MENU_SELECT METADATA_RECEIVED MICROPHONE
MIN_VALUE MISSING_SKIN_STYLE MITER MOTION_CHANGE MOTION_END MOTION_FINISH MOTION_LOOP MOTION_RESUME
MOTION_START MOTION_STOP MOTION_UPDATE MOUSE MOUSE_DOWN MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE MOUSE_LEAVE MOUSE_MOVE
MOUSE_OUT MOUSE_OVER MOUSE_UP MOUSE_WHEEL MOVE MULTIPLY
NAVIGATION NEGATIVE_INFINITY NET_STATUS NEVER NEW_COLUMN NEW_ROW NONE NORMAL NO_BITRATE_MATCH NO_BORDER
NO_CONNECTION NO_SCALE NULL_URL_LOAD NUMERIC NUMPAD_0 NUMPAD_1 NUMPAD_2 NUMPAD_3 NUMPAD_4 NUMPAD_5
NUMPAD_6 NUMPAD_7 NUMPAD_8 NUMPAD_9 NUMPAD_ADD NUMPAD_DECIMAL NUMPAD_DIVIDE NUMPAD_ENTER NUMPAD_MULTIPLY
NUMPAD_SUBTRACT NUM_PAD NaN
OFF ON OTHER OUT OUTER OVERLAY
PAD PAGE_DOWN PAGE_UP PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED PENDING PI PIXEL PLAYHEAD_UPDATE PLAYING PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED
POLLED PORTRAIT POSITIVE_INFINITY POST PRE_DATA_CHANGE PRIVACY PROGRESS
RADIAL READY RED REFLECT REGULAR REMOTE REMOVE REMOVED REMOVED_FROM_STAGE REMOVE_ALL RENDER
RENDERER_STYLES REPEAT RESIZE RESIZING RETURNINDEXEDARRAY REWINDING RGB ROLL_OUT ROLL_OVER
SCALE_X SCALE_Y SCREEN SCROLL SCRUB_FINISH SCRUB_START SECURITY_ERROR SEEKED SEEKING SELECT
SETTINGS_MANAGER SHIFT SHORT_VERSION SHOW_ALL SIZE SKEW_X SKEW_Y SKIN_ERROR SKIN_LOADED SOCKET_DATA SORT
SOUND_COMPLETE SOUND_UPDATE SPACE SQRT1_2 SQRT2 SQUARE STANDARD STATE STATE_CHANGE STATUS STOPPED
STOPPED_STATE_ENTERED STYLES SUBPIXEL SYNC
TAB TAB_CHILDREN_CHANGE TAB_ENABLED_CHANGE TAB_INDEX_CHANGE TEXT_INPUT TEXT_NODE THUMB THUMB_DRAG
THUMB_PRESS THUMB_RELEASE TIMER TIMER_COMPLETE TIME_CHANGE TOP TOP_LEFT TOP_RIGHT TRACK
TextInput_disabledSkin TextInput_upskin
UNIQUESORT UNKNOWN UNLOAD UNSUPPORTED_PROPERTY UP UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA UTC
VARIABLES VERSION VERTICAL
WRAP
```

Answer (score 2):

The public API docs don't include quite everything (there are always some methods that must be public, but aren't designed for use in application code). The public definitions are all contained in playerglobal.swc and airglobal.swc. These are available in the Flex and AIR SDKs. They, of course, can change everytime Adobe does a release of Flash Player or AIR. Given your project, I presume you already know how to extract the API names from the SWC files. (I can't really help with that, but SWFDump in the SDK might be useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the source files for AS3 IDE plugins, such as:

- [XCode ActionScript Plugin](http://coreswf.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/language/ActionScript.xclangspec)
- [FlashDevelop: AS3.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/master/FlashDevelop/Bin/Debug/Settings/Languages/AS3.xml)
- [ActionScript 3 Class Interface Implementations](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/02/29/actionscript-3-class-interface-implementations/)